# Enable WeBlog comments in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, weblog

First time I am using WeBlog in Sitecore. I have created entry, In this entry after post comment it shows message of "Thank you for your comment. If it does not require moderation, it will appear shortly" but I have no idea how comment will display? and what changes I have to do in workflow.Can anybody suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

By default weblog has a comment workflow, you can find the settings for this under: system/workflows/weblog comments

More info in workflow here:

https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/wiki/Comment-Workflow

Comments are created in the master database as child items underneath the blog post item in Sitecore. By default the comments are auto approved when saved and should automatically publish through to the web database. You can easily change this by adjusting the workflow as described in the post on comment workflow.

Comment: Could be a number of things. Have you made sure comments are enabled on the blog settings?

Comment: do you have any further details? Do you have the necessary renderings on the page for rendering comments? Is everything published including all the templates for Weblog?

Comment: yes comments are enabled. Can you please tell me in which table comments will save in master database so I can check comments is saving or not.

Comment: Comments are stored as items, they will be underneath your blog post item in the content tree.